# Subscription Management Platform

Tags: open-source, ecommerce

We are in search for an open source software which aids ins selling digital products or services. The services are either memberships which require recurring payments and renewal or one-off products which are only paid once.

If you take a look at the landscape for e-Commerce software all are mainly aimed for selling physical goods, e.g. Magento, Shopware. Even frameworks like Spryker or Thelia offer libraries for integration with logistics service providers. As we only offer a handful of products, we don't need the features which are core to these solutions like product presentation, categorization, filtering and search.

Now, the solution we need should do the following:

- simple checkout funnel with sign up form and possibility to integrate with payment service provider
- invoice generation and storage
- product management for above mentioned product types, including set up fees, cancellation periods, renewals, validity periods
- reminder management
- recurring payments
- vouchers, discounts, rebates

Preferred language would be PHP. Also, because it needs to be integrated, the system should offer REST APIs for all functionalities.

We found some promising SaaS solutions like cleverbrigde or billwerk, but these require all customer data. We would prefer a solution than can be self-hosted.

Comment: Have you investigated a CMS solution like Drupal with an UberCart module?

Comment: Actually, we are using Drupal already. But for me, this is a CMS for static content and blog content and not a subscription management platform. I have seen too many CMS and CRMs getting bloated with stuff that is actually not their core purpose resulting in horrible workflows and technical debt.

Comment: Have you looked at Gumroad (https://gumroad.com/features)? I heard about it some time ago.

Comment: Isn't that SaaS as well?

Comment: Yes it is. I don't know of a self-hosted solution.